# Finding Dictionary values based on object/type members

Tags: c#

I have dictionary defined like below,

```
Dictionary<string, SampleObject> test = new Dictionary<string, SampleObject>();

test.Add("A", null);

test.Add("B", new SampleObject()
{
    ID = "1",
    Value1 = "BBBBB1",
    Value2 = "BBBBB2"
});

test.Add("C", new SampleObject()
{
    ID = "1",
    Value1 = "CDCDCD1",
    Value2 = "CDCDCD2"
});

test.Add("D", new SampleObject()
{
    ID = "2",
    Value1 = "XXFFA",
    Value2 = "XXFFB"
});
```

How do I get list/count where object/type is null?

How do I get list/count where object/type property (ID = 1)?

I tried this and getting an error.

```
var ones = test.Where(t => t.Value.ID.Equals("1"));
```

Comment: try adding a null check:  `test.Where(t => (t.Value != null) && t.Value.ID.Equals("1"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to weed out the nulls first:

```
var nulls = test.Count(c => c.Value == null);
var ones = test.Count(c => c.Value != null && c.Value.ID == "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first item that you are adding to your dictionary is `null`, so when executing the predicate `t.Value.ID.Equals("1")`, for that value `t.Value` is `null` and the error that you are getting is a `NullReferenceException`.

The code is bascially correct, you could avoid adding `null` values to your dictionary, or testing for them in your predicate:

```
var ones = test.Where(t => t.Value != null && t.Value.ID.Equals("1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get count of `null` object this way:

```
var ones = test.Where(t => t.Value == null).Count();
```

and for object with ID equals to  1 :

```
var ones = test.Where(t => t.Value != null && t.Value.ID == 1).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see good answers already. 
Just would like to add that from C# 6.0 you will be able to use Null-Conditional Operator:
[c# 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx).
And your code will be fine with small modification adding ? where the null appear on value.

```
var ones = test.Where(t => t.Value?.ID.Equals("1"));
```